# Casting a generic entity using reflection with generic method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I have a method called `RevertChanges` which looks like the following:

```
public static void RevertChanges<TEntity>()
{
            var jsonData = DataAccess.GetEnvironmentJson((int)Environments.Production);
            var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.FullDataSetModel>(jsonData);
            var targetEntity = typeof(TEntity).Name;
            using (var db = new LoginPageContentEntities())
            {
                db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(String.Format("TRUNCATE TABLE [{0}]", targetEntity));
                var modelValue = model.GetType().GetProperty(targetEntity).GetValue(model, null);
                var table = (DbSet)(typeof(LoginPageContentEntities).GetProperty(targetEntity).GetValue(db, null));
                table.AddRange((DbSet)modelValue);                         
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
}
```

I know that whatever `TEntity` is will match the modelValue data set. DbSet casting does not work and I am struggling to find how you can return an entire entity with generics.  I have found that if I cast with `(IEnumerable<TEntity>)` I am able to call `ToList()` on table, however this will not work as I need to be able to call add range.  Is it possible to:

1. Return an entity reference with generics?
2. Access `AddRange` and then
   save the context?

For context I am trying to replace this method:

```
public static void RevertChanges(Environments targetToRestoreFrom, ContentFields tableToRevert)
        {
            var jsonData = DataAccess.GetEnvironmentJson((int)targetToRestoreFrom);
            var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.FullDataSetModel>(jsonData);            
            using (var db = new LoginPageContentEntities())
            {
                switch (tableToRevert)
                {
                    case ContentFields.ProductInformation:
                        db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE [ProductInformation]");
                        db.ProductInformation.AddRange(model.ProductInformation);
                        break;
                    case ContentFields.DidYouKnow:
                        db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE [DidYouKnow]");
                        db.DidYouKnow.AddRange(model.DidYouKnow);
                        break;
                    case ContentFields.MaintenanceMessage:
                        db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE [MaintenanceMessage]");
                        db.MaintenanceMessage.AddRange(model.MaintenanceMessage);
                        break;
                    case ContentFields.TrainingEvent:
                        db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE [TrainingEvents]");
                        db.TrainingEvents.AddRange(model.TrainingEvents);
                        break;
                    case ContentFields.VideoContent:
                        db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE [HtmlSnippets]");
                        db.HtmlSnippets.AddRange(model.HtmlSnippets);
                        break;
                    case ContentFields.ProductMarketingUrl:
                        db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE [ProductMarketingUrl]");
                        db.ProductMarketingUrl.AddRange(model.ProductMarketingUrl);
                        break;
                }                
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

Model:

```
namespace LoginPageContentManager.Models
{
    public class FullDataSetModel
    {
        public List<DidYouKnow> DidYouKnow                   { get; set; }
        public List<HtmlSnippets> HtmlSnippets               { get; set; }
        public List<MaintenanceMessage> MaintenanceMessage   { get; set; }
        public List<ProductInformation> ProductInformation   { get; set; }
        public List<TrainingEvents> TrainingEvents           { get; set; }
        public List<ProductMarketingUrl> ProductMarketingUrl { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered creating a class `Models.FullDataSetModel<TEntity>`?

Comment: Have you tried using Reflection to invoke `AddRange` instead of casting to DbSet<T>?

Comment: @Aron I have not, going to add an edit of what that model looks like. I am not sure how that would be helpful as I would still need to return that entity type and if you do that then you should be able to reference it from the base database context.

Comment: @Hopeless How would one go about doing that?

Comment: @Hopeless In fact you should really use `DbContext.Set<TEntity>()`.

Comment: @ZachM. Usually you would have (I assume this is a web API) a different REST end point for each "table". Or you could even possible just use OData instead of creating your own custom API. You just have to invent your own `Truncate` verb, which is the equivalent of thermonuclear war button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Set<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.set(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbContext.Set%60%601) method allows you to get a `DbSet` generically.

In your case, you should be able to add to the set by doing:

```
db.Set<TEntity>().AddRange(modelValue)
```

Comment: This won't work because TEntity in this method would need to be the correct type, error thrown is `The type TEntity must be a reference type in order to use it as a parameter....`

Comment: @ZachM. so try adding constraint for your method like this `public static void RevertChanges<TEntity>() where TEntity : class { ... }`

Comment: @Hopeless Yep that did it, my experience with reflection is tenuous at best so this was very helpful.

Comment: @Hopeless could you elaborate on why this is needed on the end of the method? what function does simply stating TEntity is a class do?

Comment: @ZachM. Because `Set<T>` requires that `T` is a reference type (because entities must be classes, not structs), so it follows that anything you pass as an argument to `T` must also have this constraint.

Comment: @ZachM. `TEntity` is a generic argument type, it could be any without any constraint. Because the Set<T> requires a reference generic type, so the constraint `where TEntity : class` will ensure it can be safely passed-in `Set<T>`. You can read more about this here [Constraints on Type Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use `Set(Type entityType)` [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679544(v=vs.103).aspx) on `DbContext`.

Something like this (not compiled or tested):

```
var setType = typeof(MyModel).GetProperty(targetEntity).GetType();
db.Set(setType).AddRange(modelValue)
```

Comment: The type of setType when implemented this way ends up being `setType {Name = "RuntimePropertyInfo" FullName = "System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo"} System.Type {System.RuntimeType}` This is returning

Comment: Yes, I've missed something from your question. Seems like the accepted answer works for you anyway.